# IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent never returns to onActivityResult(int, int, Intent);

Tags: java, android

I start an `IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent like this, and my activity's `onActivityResult()` get called:

```
Intent i = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, null);
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_ICON_FROM_CAMERA_ID);
```

But, if I start my Intent like this, the Capture Image Intent did get called, but my activity's `onActivityResult()` never get called:

```
Intent i = new Intent (android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, null);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.parse("file:/" + "MyTestFile"));
i.putExtra("outputFormat",    Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_ICON_FROM_CAMERA_ID);
```

Can you please tell me how to get the 2<sup>nd</sup> case to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "file:/MyTestFile" is an incorrect uri. Try something like that:

```
File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "MyTestFile");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(f));
```

The actual path would be "/sdcard/MyTestFile".